# Create an exe with Python 3.4 using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I have found two other articles about this problem on Stack Exchange but none of them has a clear answer: is it possible to create a .exe of a Python 3.4 script? The only solution I found was to use cx_Freeze. I used it, and it indeed created an executable with the dll and everything. However, if I click on it, I get:

```
name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Of course, I used Python 3.4, not 2.7. In my code, I used "input()" but it seems that the executable changed input() to raw_input(). Therefore, I would like to know a way to compile my code into an .exe compatible with Python 3.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to convert python script to exe have a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and it worked. Now py2exe works for Python 3.4!